# JQuery immediately removes class after adding

Tags: jquery, html, class

I used JQuery function to add remove class in HTML link element by checking with firebug JQuery actually added the class and then removes back immediately.
anybody know why? [here is fiddle](https://youtu.be/BJR9vocNerw)

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/aqeelpld/7yydg1nt/2/
```

[watch this on youtube](https://youtu.be/BJR9vocNerw)

Comment: Works fine for me on Firefox 37. What browser are you using?

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't work this way. You need to do it either with PHP or check the URL you are on and compare it with the links in your anchor tags.

Comment: Firefox 37.0.2, chrome 42.0.2311 and IE 11.0.9600 same problem across all browsers!

Comment: can you plz tell me how to check and compare links or how i can achieve this with php?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your link is reloading the page.  If you are using jQuery, change the href to "#" to stop it from reloading index.html.  If you must link to another PHP page, then you should be checking which page you are on in your PHP and adding the 'active' class there, on page load.  Via PHP...

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER('REQUEST_URI');
$class = 'nonactive';
if ($uri=='/index.php') $class = 'active';
echo '<a href="..." class="'.$class.'">...</a>'
$class = 'nonactive';
if ($uri=='/nexUri.php') $class = 'active';
echo '<a href="..." class="'.$class.'">...</a>'
$class = 'nonactive';
?>
```

...via jQuery...

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    if ($(location).attr('href')=='/index.php')
        $('#indexLinkId').addClass('active');
    else if ($(location).attr('href')=='/nextUri.php')
        $('#nextUriLinkId').addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7yydg1nt/3/

Comment: thanks for reply, yes its works that way but as you know this is nat a solution! what wrong with this, any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong is that you are linking to a page and therefore the page is reloading.  When the page reloads, you lose your updated class, it's just like refreshing the page.  What are you looking for as a solution???

Comment: i wanted to open and remain the page in the same window meanwhile clicked link remain unique from other links (as i described it in the css class). remember i used this navigation as dynamically across different pages with php.

Comment: If you are reloading the page, then you need to add the class either dynamically in the PHP (as the updated solution states) or after page load.  Either way you will need to check the page name and update the class via if/else statements.  Your only other option would be to use frames.

Comment: sorry i didn't know much php and i have no idea! any recommendations or source i must checkout?

Comment: or any hint or examples!

Comment: thanks! try this then i will tell u what happened.thanks again.

Comment: sorry to say but its not working! plz anybody help me. every site has this function its the integral part of any site then why it is so big problem for me!

Comment: Which method did you use?  I would prefer not to mess with both if you are leaning towards one in particular.

Comment: i tried both but now i really wanted php, plz help me!

Comment: now this code works fine for me!  <?php 
$index="menu-items";
$top_albums_default="menu-items";
$Topartists="menu-items";
$Toplists="menu-items";
$Charts="menu-items";
$menuLinkid=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],".php");
if($menuLinkid=="index"){
    $index='active';
}else if ($menuLinkid=="top_albums_default"){
    $top_albums_default='active';
}else if ($menuLinkid=="Topartists"){
    $Topartists='active';
}else if ($menuLinkid=="Toplists"){
    $Toplists='active';
}else if ($menuLinkid=="Charts"){
    $Charts='active';
}
?>